# look up filter failing while doing copy paste

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, lookup-filter

I have a custom lookup filter on an opportunity to show only active records of a custom object (look up relation ship) . Its working well in regular process but its failing when I do copy paste of inactive record. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: inactive record means?

Comment: @Santanu Boral, I have a status field on my Lookup Object.  If it is true then only that record will show in lookup.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fixed this issue by adding a validation rule.

Comment: Please share the content of this validation rule if it helped resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it's because you have applied filter which is used for displaying the records for the look up. But if you copy paste it is not going to restrict that.

To achieve this you need to write a trigger and you need to check whether the look up value is an active one or not.

Hope this helps.